# how to set variable using fetched array in php

Tags: php

I have a query that fetches values from a database and I'd like to store an instance of the value 'current' into a variable for reuse.

My fetch is currently:

```
function updateTable() {
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
global $connection;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "current: " . $row["current"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}  
}}
```

As you can see I have been able to confirm the values are being fetched by echoing out the array. What I'd like to do now is to store the first instance of the array into a new variable called $total.

I have been able to separate the array and echo values using:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $value = $row ['current'];
    if($row['id'] == 2){
    echo $value;
    }               
                }
```

I had thought storing the value would be similar but I can't get it to work.

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
James

Comment: `if(empty($value)) { $value=$row['current']; }` - note, that if the first $row['current'] is 0, '', null it will 'try again' in next round...

Comment: alternatively you could add a simple counter. asking for row['id'] is not such a good idea. (what if the result is sorted alphabetically? What if the first id is 924?)

Comment: I've got it! it was after just a case of me needing to set the variable in the while loop.

Comment: I did think that there must be a better way, I'll defiantly look into the idea of a counter next. (I'm only on day 2 of php)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "current: " . $row["current"];
    }
}
```

instead of

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$i = 1;
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $$current.$i = $row["current"];



    }
    echo $$current1;
    echo $$current2;
}
```

Comment: `$i` will stay 1

Answer (score 0):

Create array of values when the key is the id and the value is the current then after for loop echo the value where key is 2

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$values[$row['id']]=$row ['current'];
}               
}
echo $values[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function updateTable() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    global $connection;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM myTable";
    $constant = array();
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "current: " . $row["current"];
            **$constant['output'] =  $row["WhatEverShow"];** 
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }  
    }}


**print_r($constant['output']);**

Hope This help you
```